# How to check for Range of Values (domain) in a Dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dns

So want to determine what values are in a Pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'col1': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7], 'col2': [3, 4, 3, 5, 7,22,3]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

col2 hast the unique values 3,4,5,6,22 (domain). Each value that exists shall be determined. But only once.

Is there anyway to fastly extract what the domain is in a Pandas Dataframe Column?

Comment: Do you mean `print(df["col2"].unique())` ?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "domain".

Comment: Andrej has the solution. What is the correct term if not "domain"? Codomain?

Comment: @MarK I think in this case it would be easier to understand calling it a `set`. Domain is for a function, there's not really a function here.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print(df["col2"].unique())
```

by Andrej Kesely is the solution. Perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`df.max()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) and [`df.min()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.min.html) to find the range.